в unity не получается добавить объект текстового типа в скрипт, где прописано место для текстового объекта
возможно вопрос супер нелепый, но я пока только учусь.
В юнити я добавила текстовый объект и хочу его же добавить в скрипт, где прописано место для текста:
public Text resourcesText;

Но когда по факту я пытаюсь перетащить объект, то юнити показывает, что текстовых объектов в сцене нет.

Не существует такой ошибки, как текстовых объектов в сцене нет!

Я примерно понял, о чем вы. Если вам нужно взять со сцены Text (Лучше использовать Text Mesh Pro, т.к. обычный Text в Unity уже помечен как Legacy, проще говоря, устаревший), то вы должны создать его в канвасе (Это - элемент UI.).
Дальше вы берёте именно этот созданный Text, и перетаскиваете на скрипт.
(В скрипте тоже должен быть указан именно Text Mesh Pro). Пример кода:
using TMPro;

public class TextSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text text;

    public void Update()
    {
        text.text = "Hello, World!";
    }
}

(На примере сразу видно, как можно работать с самим значением текста)
